# Remove leading "Copy of" string from a varchar column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my table I want to remove first 7 characters from the `Title` column.

I have a table like below and I want to remove the `'Copy of'` prefix:

```
Title
---------------------
Copy ofthis is tile1
Copy ofthis is another tile2
```

I tried this:

```
Update MyTable SET Title=(SELECT RIGHT(Title,LEN(Title)- 7) AS Title) 
  WHERE Title LIKE 'Copy of%'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually the query you have, while it doesn't *look* right on first glance, is valid syntax and seems to work. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a subquery for this, and generally you don't need to check the length to figure out how long the output should be. Assuming this isn't a `varchar(max)`, you could do:

```
UPDATE dbo.MyTable
  SET Title = SUBSTRING(Title, 8, 8000)
  WHERE Title LIKE 'Copy of%';
```

Or you could do:

```
UPDATE dbo.MyTable
  SET Title = STUFF(Title, 1, 7, '')
  WHERE Title LIKE 'Copy of%';
```

You may also want to use `LTRIM()` in case the value is `'Copy of something'` and you don't want a leading space:

```
UPDATE dbo.MyTable
  SET Title = LTRIM(STUFF(Title, 1, 7, ''))
  WHERE Title LIKE 'Copy of%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the SUBSTRING function.

```
update mytable set value = substring  ( value, 8, len (value) )
where value like 'copy of%'
```

Comment: This actually leaves the `f` so with the sample data you end up with `fthis is tile1` and `fthis is another tile2`.